# date and time picker with validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquerydatetimepicker

I got a greater example of validating period with date picker without time.
Is it possible to make the validation with date and time together?

The Example from: 
http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/01/end-date-should-not-be-greater-than.html

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#txtFromDate").datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    maxDate: "+60D",
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    onSelect: function(selected) {
      $("#txtToDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", selected)
    }
  });
  $("#txtToDate").datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    maxDate: "+60D",
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    onSelect: function(selected) {
      $("#txtFromDate").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selected)
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" /> From:
<input type="text" id="txtFromDate" /> To:
<input type="text" id="txtToDate" />
```

Comment: can you elaborate your question what you want?

Comment: he wants a date-time picker with validation.

Comment: First of all you need a [date-time picker](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/). Only then you deal with validation...

Comment: I am a beginner in javascript could you please help me with a nice example? Thanks.